# can't get jquery autocomplete styled

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, themes

I have the jquery autocomplete example working on a test page, but can't seem to get the dropdown list styled.  It just shows up as an ordinary ul with li items (not the white background box with a list as in the example).  I have tried this alone and with the redmond theme, any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?  I see the redmond stylesheets in firebug, so the page is loading them.

js (working)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").autocomplete({
        source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
    });
});
```

css/js includes

```
<script src="/public/javascripts/jquery-1.6.2.js'"></script>
<script src="/public/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/javascripts/ac.js"></script> // where the above js is 
<script src="/public/javascripts/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/public/stylesheets/redmond/jquery.ui.all.css"/>
```

here is the input:

```
<input name="searchString" type="text" class="searchbox ui-autocomplete" id="autocomplete"/>
```

(edit: added CSS, overlooked this when writing the question)

Comment: Isn't there a missing CSS file or two in your includes? I only see JS files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download a theme and include the theme's CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
```

You can see the themes [here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#themeGallery), and just download them from the [download page](http://jqueryui.com/download) by selecting the theme you want in the right-hand bar..

Edit: It looks like you're using the old jQuery [auto-complete plug-in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) which has been discontinued. You can try the following CSS for that if you wish. I STRONGLY recommend you use the jQuery UI autocomplete however.

```
/* Autocomplete styles */
.ac_results {
        padding: 0px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 99999;
}

.ac_results ul {
        width: 100%;
        list-style-position: outside;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
}

.ac_results li {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 2px 5px;
        cursor: default;
        display: block;
        /*
        if width will be 100% horizontal scrollbar will apear
        when scroll mode will be used
        */
        /*width: 100%;*/
        font: menu;
        font-size: 12px;
        /*
        it is very important, if line-height not setted or setted
        in relative units scroll will be broken in firefox
        */
        line-height: 16px;
        overflow: hidden;
}

.ac_loading {
        /* loader image */
        background: white url('indicator.gif') right center no-repeat;
}

.ac_odd {
        background-color: #eee;
}

.ac_over {
        background-color: #0A246A;
        color: white;
}
```

Comment: sorry, added the CSS entry (forgot to add this in the question).  All of the css files from the redmond theme are loaded when I bring up the page in firebug.

Comment: Are you using the old jQuery [auto-complete plug-in](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)? If so, this would be why redmond theme isn't working, and I recommend trying out the [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). I checked the Redmond theme, and it has the correct CSS entries to theme jQuery UI auto-complete. It should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't think I am, I picked up jquery and jquery-ui off of jquery.com and jqueryui.com respectively (earlier today).  I changed my syntax to match that of the example you posted in [your link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and it is still the same results, a plain 'ole <ul> list that is unstyled.

Comment: Where did you get ac.js? I'm assuming that ac.js is your autocomplete plugin. If it is, then it's likely the old one I told you about, because jQuery UI autocomplete is built into jQuery UI itself, and only requires the component was selected to use when you customized it for download.

Comment: ac.js is just the javascript above.  I updated it to reflect the example, and changed the id of the input to 'tags' to try the method in the example, w/o luck

Comment: Ok, I gotcha. ;) The themes also come with an images folder. Do you have that folder in the same directory as the themes CSS?

Comment: It could also be a problem with your CSS selector. `("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({`

Comment: You know, I didn't have the images folder (nice catch)...so I just added it with the contained images, but it still isn't styled.  You are probably right on the selector, do you have a recommended method for this?

Comment: thanks for your help, i'll play with it a bit and see if I can get it working

Comment: If you were satisfied with the answer, could you please mark this as "best answer"? :)

Comment: What if you have two themes? Or one main theme, and just one part you want to stylize? I wouldn't recommend adding another min. 20kb file to your project for a seemingly 6 or 8 lines of code.

Answer (score -1):

Use below theme in your application and it should work (add it in your master page/template OR on the page where you implement auto-complete feature.)

jquery.ui.theme.css